# Allow users to change font size in a webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to be able to change the size of text in a web page, I guess jQuery can be used, but I have no experience in javascript.

Another problem is that the webpage is a phtml file, and multiple php echo commands are used. And the page is made up of multiple phtml files.

EDIT: I would like to give users 3 choices for different font sizes.

Comment: Do not mess font sizes! You have no idea, what is appropriate for the user. Keep font sizes the way they are. And do not fail to think you can decide what is best for the user better than the user itself.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The approach I would take is to apply a font-size percentage to the body tag of the html

```
body
{
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

Then for all other elements specify font-size in ems, which generates the size as a scaled up percentage of the inherited font-size

```
h1
{
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

p
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

I use 62.5% on the body because it is easy to translate this to pixel sizes when specifying other font sizes e.g. 1.2em = 12px, 1.8em = 18px and so on

To then change the font size in the page programatically you just need to change the value of the font-size on the body and the rest of the page will scale up or down accordingly

You can test this by having three divs

```
<div id="sizeUp">bigger text</div>
<div id="normal">normal text</div>
<div id="sizeDown">smaller text</div>
```

In JQuery I believe you can do

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#sizeUp").click(function() {

        $("body").css("font-size","70%");

    });

    $("#normal").click(function() {

        $("body").css("font-size","62.5%");

    })

    $("#sizeDown").click(function() {

        $("body").css("font-size","55%");

    })
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. is there any file that I need to import for JQuery?

Comment: Yes go to http://jquery.com/ and there is a download link on the right hand side. You need to include a reference to the downloaded js file in your html head. There is also access to documentation with examples of usage

Comment: I thought why 62.5%. Then found that [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems) article explains it.

Comment: Wouldn't rem be more accurate and easier to handle than em if you are changing the body elements?

Answer (score 2):

How to increase and reduce font size of div content through jquery?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">

sghfhj jhkjik jhbjbjbh 
 </div>

 <div ><input type="button" value="increase" class="increaseFont"></input></div>
 <div><input type="button" value="decrease" class="decreaseFont"></input></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".increaseFont,.decreaseFont").click(function(){
  var type=  $(this).val();
   var curFontSize = $('.data').css('font-size');
   alert(curFontSize);
   if(type=='increase'){
    $('.data').css('font-size', parseInt(curFontSize)+1);
    }
   else{
    $('.data').css('font-size', parseInt(curFontSize)-1);
   }
   alert($('.data').css('font-size'));

     });


 });
 </script>
```

this is working :)

Answer (score 1):

I use this, with font awsome:

```
Fontsize: 
<div class="fa fa-search-plus" id="sizeUp"></div>
<div class="fa fa-search" id="normal"></div>
<div class="fa fa-search-minus" id="sizeDown"></div>
```

and the script:

```
<script async type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#sizeUp").click(function(){
          var curFontSize = $('.ccm-page').css('font-size');
           $(".ccm-page").css("font-size",parseInt(curFontSize)+1);
         });

        $("#normal").click(function() {
            $(".ccm-page").css("font-size","15px");

        })

        $("#sizeDown").click(function() {
            var curFontSize = $('.ccm-page').css('font-size');
            $(".ccm-page").css("font-size",parseInt(curFontSize)-1);
        })
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to change the text size is with css. If you have access to the css file, you can change the size of all text on the page with this:

```
* {
    font-size: 110%;
  }
```

Add it to the top of your styles.css file, it affects all text on the page, and all text that use the styles.css file.

Comment: yes. the above works perfectly with jquery. $("*").css({"font-size":"100.5%"});

Comment: but when reducing with percentage it does not reduce as expected.

Comment: This will only work as you probably intend if your font sizes on the page are defined in ems (a relative measure) and not in px (an absolute measure).

Answer (score 0):

Simply with jQuery and HTML you can add an option to increase/decrease the font size of your text. You have to wrap the content in a div with class `kickblogger` and target that div to change it's font size using jQuery. Use this script.

```
<script src=" https://googledrive.com/host/0Bw5Ph-OwuTz6VkJhZmNlX1lJV0k/"> </script>
```

With these buttons.

```
<input type="button" id="btnkickplus" value="A +" />
<input type="button" id="btnkickminus" value="A -" />
```

- Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/3N4Lf/
- Article -
  http://www.howtokickblogger.com/2013/09/change-text-font-size-on-blogger-using-jquery.html

:)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="document.body.style.fontSize='x-small';">SMALL</a></p>
<p><a href="#" onclick="document.body.style.fontSize='medium';">MEDIUM</a></p>
<p><a href="#" onclick="document.body.style.fontSize='x-large';">BIG</a></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just resize the font by CTRL-+ and CTRL-- (in Firefox, might be different in other browsers)

Comment: But its not font size, its page zoom.