# CSS - Increase Page Font Size

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Allow users to change font size in a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891980/allow-users-to-change-font-size-in-a-webpage)

I have some webpages. I would like the user to click an image and have the font-sizes of all of the content on the page increase. Is this possible? If so, how?

I know that the browsers have options inside of them. Basically, I want a way to do that in the page itself.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891980/change-font-size-in-a-webpage/892031

Answer (score 32):

Three things to achieve this:

Specify the overall font-size in the `<body>` tag. For example:

```
body { font-size: 100%; }
```

Don't use pixels to specify font-size anywhere else in the document.

```
p.somePara { font-size: 120%; }
p.anotherPara { font-size: 1.4em; }
```

Attach an event handler to this image, to adjust the font size accordingly.  Using jQuery, for example:

```
$("#largerTextImage").click(function() {
  $("body").css("fontSize", "120%");
});
```

Done.

Comment: Edited to fix a itty bitty syntax error :)

Answer (score 1):

If you increase the font size of a top-level element like `<body>`, then that [changed] size will be inherited by its child elements (assuming that other CSS rules for those element didn't override that size with an absolute value, which would also have messed up the user's changing font size in their browser).

[This article](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domstylesheets) (for example) says that it describes how to change CSS values programatically.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you could switch css.

Put all your font-sizes in a separated CSS file. Then duplicate this file and change the font sizes. Then use a piece of js script to swich css files.

There are a lot of tutorials up there that explain all about it. [Here's one](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/css-simple-style-switcher/).

Comment: This is a very crude method that I would never use.

Comment: Why that? This is pretty interesting since you can specify different font sizes for all the elements to keep control over what your website looks like.

Comment: 1) changing out the CSS files like that is actually a bit crude, using classes that you add/remove on the body would be better as it would be instant update, no new file downloading just to change the font size. 2) This method is far more appropriate for small scale changes than for site-wide font adjusting. That's a lot of extra CSS writing for such a little feature. Far better that if you need this feature you do % or em based methods like explained by bigmattyh's answer and leave the method from this answer to smaller scale toggling jobs.