# Way to increase font-size for entire site?

Tags: jquery, css

I can increase the font size on a single page using Jquery as such:

```
$(function(){
    $("#fontsizebtn").click(function() {
        $("#content").toggleClass("sizeincrease");
    });
});
```

That's fine. But the user will need to click the button again for each page they visit.

Is there a way to do this so it carries across to all pages? Would I need to alter a file server side, or is there another way of doing it? (Not expecting detailed answer, just point me in the right direction)

EDIT: for those saying that this question is a duplicate to: [CSS - Increase Page Font Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386531/css-increase-page-font-size) this user seems to want to increase the text-size for a single page (which I can already achieve). I want to increase the text-size for all pages so a visitor only needs to click the increase size button once.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386531/css-increase-page-font-size

Comment: @Moogs thanks but that doesnt solve the problem - I want to increase font size for all pages, not just the one they are visitiing

Comment: store the user's preference in a session cookie, indexDB, or local storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example `sessionStorage` is used to retain the user's preference. sessionStorage is destroyed when the tab or browser window is closed. Use `localStorage` to persist after browser closed if you want.

```
var percent = restore() || 100;

$('#increase').click(function () {
    percent += 10;
    setFontSize(percent);
});

$('#decrease').click(function () {
    percent -= 10;
    setFontSize(percent);
});

function save(percent) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('fontSize', percent);
}

function restore() {
    percent = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('fontSize'));
    setFontSize(percent);
    return percent;
}

function setFontSize(percent) {
    $('body').css('fontSize', percent + '%');
    save(percent);
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/tvbt0a3L/2/**

Answer (score 2):

One idea:

You can use `local-storage` to store the user preference for the font-size and read their preference for each page loaded. However, their preference will be valid for the current computer only.

You can save the user preference like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('font-size','smallClass');
```

Later, you can do this:

```
var fontSizeClass = localStorage.getItem('font-size');
$("#content").addClass(fontSizeClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add something like  `font-size:99px !important;` into body in your css.

Comment: But how exactly? Use AJAX to trigger a PHP script to write that on the .css file?

Comment: Download file in ftp and make the change then upload...  or just call you jquery script 9n document load instead of on click

Comment: If you are looking for an on demand option use answer from other guy above

Comment: sorry you misunderstand. I want the site user to be able to control font size during their visit  for the entire site by only clicking the button once.

Comment: The local storage option by erkaner  above would be best