# Change font size according to user input using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, forms, font-size

I have the following code:

```
<div id="font">
            <h2>Font Size</h2>
            <input type="text" name="font" value="15" /> px
            <br /><span id="warning"></span>
        </div>
```

which allows the user to input a font size into the form and the text would change according to what the user puts in, 
additionally I would like for a warning to appear beside the input area if the user enters a font size smaller than 10px,
how could I do this using jquery? I have tried several things that have not been successful so far

Thanks!

Comment: why not set the minimum value to 10 so that the user can't go below ?

Comment: Please show what you tried

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow users to change font size in a webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891980/allow-users-to-change-font-size-in-a-webpage)

Comment: Do you want to change font size from use input or add a warning for a font smaller than 10px? From the way the question is asked it seems like you already have the functionality to change the font size (which makes the title confusing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `keyup` handler on your input element and when that event fires check that the value is less than 10, then update your desired element. This way it will update right away after the user changes the value. Here is an example:

```js
$("input").keyup(function(){
    if( parseInt($(this).val()) < 10 ) {
        $("#warning").text("Your font is smaller than 10px");
    } else {
        $("#warning").text("");
        $('#testFont').css('font-size', $(this).val() + 'px');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="font">
            <h2>Font Size</h2>
            <input type="text" name="font" value="15" /> px
            <br /><span id="warning"></span>
        </div>
<br />
<div id="testFont">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried this and it worked, but the warning wouldn't display and if the font size was smaller than 10 the text would still change to that font size, can this be fixed?

Comment: @mch Sure, you just have to change the text size if it's larger than 10 (in the else statement). I will add that change, although I don't see what you mean that the warning isn't displaying. I'm getting a warning in the example. Are you not getting the text *"Your font is smaller than 10px"* when you enter a value such as "9" or "8"?

Comment: Yeah somehow it doesn't appear when I run it on my website.. I'll try to find out what's going on, the warning appears on here perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @mch Make sure you have a single element with an id of `"warning"` like in the example: `<span id="warning"></span>`.

Comment: turns out I had the wrong id! it works perfectly now thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this with jQuery, you should build a change handler on the input field similar to the following.  Then using the css function manipulate the font size of the field.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fontInput').change(function(){
        if ( !$(this).val() ) {
            return;
        }
        $('.fontChanger').css('font-size', $(this).val() + 'px');
        
        if ($(this).val() < 10) {
            alert('Font too small!!!');
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="fontChanger">This is my text</p>

<p class="fontChanger">2ndary Text</p>

<p class="fontChanger">Woooo</p>

<p>Enter the new Font Size!</p>
<input type="text" id="fontInput" />
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6e11t4b7/3/

Comment: This is not good enough. Why? Cause if you click on the box but you don't enter any value that click anywhere else, you still get the alert. This is not a good practice of blur.

Answer (score 0):

You could always check for the value when the user clicks on the input like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').click(function () {
        var fontsize = $('input').val();

        if (fontsize < 10) {
            alert('Font too small!!!');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5d7xwbu6/)

OR, another way of doing it si to bind the keypress function and check for the input value, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').bind('keypress', function (e) {
        var fontsize = $('input').val();
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            if (fontsize < 10) {
                alert('Font too small!!!');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Another [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/5d7xwbu6/1/)